# Can any element absorb neutron in low energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, neutrons, absorption

I read somewhere that neutron can be absorbed by any element if we provide sufficient energy to the neutron and the element. I want to ask that if we have an energy spectrum of 1Gev/c and 10Gev/c and we fire neutrons with this much energy towards an element so can we expect the neutron to get absorbed in the nucleus of the atoms of that elemen? For example if we fire neutron within such energy rate towards Sodium gas 23, Can we expect it to become Sodium 24 and decay after 15 hours to become Magnesium 24?

Comment: Have a look at this document. http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/28/060/28060364.pdf

Comment: Low energy neutrons are much more easily absorbed by nuclei. Lots of data on cross sections at the Evaluated Nuclear Data Files project at bnl.gov (Brookhaven National Labs).

Answer (score 1):

> For example if we fire neutron within such energy rate towards Sodium gas 23, Can we expect it to become Sodium 24 and decay after 15 hours to become Magnesium 24?

The short answer ,for the GeV energies you propose, is No. Only for low Mev energies matching the nuclear potentials such a capture would be probable.

The nuclei are bound in a type of potential well which has energy levels, and are characterized by spin and angular momentum. This is the shell model of the nucleus, [seen here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html), second page. The energy levels have an order of MeV mass differences.Even 1Gev/c is too large an energy for the neutron to be accommodated in an energy level of the nucleus. 1 GeV means 1000 MeV , and [the energy levels of nuclei](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html) are of [order of MeVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Binding_energy_curve_-_common_isotopes.svg).

For a neutron to be captured it has to approach the nucleus with an energy that is within the width of the available line, and release its energy with beta decay, and create an isotope of the original. It is called [neutron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_capture) and depends on the material.

For capture the neutron has to be of order of MeV energies.  If the energy is not appropriate for capture there can be [elastic scattering](https://neutrons.ornl.gov/sites/default/files/intro_to_neutron_scattering.pdf) which is used for studying various states of matter.

A high energy neutron will scatter off the nucleus giving various products including high energy jets of particles , destroying the original nucleus into fragments.

Answer (score 0):

All isotopes except those on the [neutron drip line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_drip_line) require energy input to *liberate* a neutron, and *release* energy when they absorb a neutron. According to the [Neutron Data Booklet](https://www.ill.eu/quick-links/publications/) in my pocket, an interaction between a thermal neutron and a sodium-23 nucleus is six or seven times more likely to be a scattering interaction than a capture interaction, but the capture cross section of $\sigma_\text{capture} = \rm0.5\,barn$ is pretty substantial.

By "thermal neutron," one usually means a neutron from an ensemble with a [Maxwellian velocity distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) consistent with mean kinetic energy of $25\,\mathrm{meV} = k_B\times(300\,\rm K)$, which is what comes out of a liquid water neutron moderator.  This is many orders of magnitude below the energies that you have in mind --- I mean milli-eV, while your other answer talks about mega-eV.  For these low energies, the neutron capture cross section is basically proportional the neutron's dwell time near the nucleus, or $(\text{speed})^{-1}$, or $(\text{energy})^{-1/2}$.  So you can improve the capture probability by slowing the neutron down.

After the neutron capture event, the daughter nucleus is typically in a highly excited state --- the excitation energy is the daughter's "neutron separation energy," which is typically about ten mega-eV.  Most of these nuclei relax to their ground state by emitting a series of gamma rays, but other modes are possible.  For example, thermal neutrons in air participate in $\rm^{14}N(n,p){}^{14}C$, which is how cosmic rays produce radioactive carbon.
These sorts of break-up reactions become more common as the energy involved in the capture increases.  I'd expect cold or thermal neutrons on sodium-23 to produce, after some delay for the beta-decay, magnesium-24.  However neutrons above a few mega-eV could knock a nucleon *out* of the sodium nucleus, and a giga-eV neutron could break the nucleus up altogether.